# Retrieve e.target.files in another method in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2

**I'm new to Vue.**
How can I access `e.target.files` from `submit()`?
Tried refs - `this.$refs.myFileInput.value` but it not gives me `FileList{File(17050)...}` object.

`console.log(e.target.files[0])` in `imageChanged(e)` gives what I need: `File(17050) {name: "hello.jpg", size: 17050, ...}`

Now the code:

```
imageChanged (e) {
      console.log(e.target.files[0])
      let files = e.target.files
      for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i])
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          this.attachedFile.allData.push({file: e.target.result, size: files[i].size, type: files[i].type, inputnameispreview: this.picked, webtemplateid: this.$route.params.id, filename: files[i].name})
        }
      }
    },
submit () {
      let self = this
      api.post('http:..', this.attachedFile)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have set ref like this

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="myInputFile" class="">
```

In Js you can access file like this

```
 this.$refs.myInputFile.files
```

Instead of

```
 this.$refs.myInputFile.value
```

Comment: Thx. I'll try at monday)